# Zeppelin SqlContext registerTempTable issue

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-zeppelin

I am trying to access some json data using sqlContext.jsonFile in zeppelin...

following code execute without any error:

```
import sys.process._
val sqlCon = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
val jfile = sqlCon.jsonFile(s"file:///usr/local/src/knoldus/projects/scaladay_data/scalaDays2015Amsterdam_tweets.json")

import sqlContext.implicits._
jfile.registerTempTable("jTable01")
```

> output :
>
> import sys.process._ sqlCon: org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext =
>   org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext@7034473 jfile:
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [*id: struct, content:
>   string, hashtags: array, score:
>   struct, session:
>   string, timestamp: bigint, tweetId: bigint, username: string] import
>   sqlContext.implicits.*

next I verify the table name which I just registered

`sqlCon.tableNames().foreach(println)`

> output :
>
> jTable01

but when I try to run following I get an error:

```
%sql
select * from jTable01
```

> output :
>
> no such table jTable01; line 1 pos 14

at the same time when I run the tutorial example for "bank" it works....
the only difference I could make out is that in bank tutorial we are using **sc.textFile** but in my case I wanted to use **sqlContext.jsonFile.**

could you please provide any guidance as how I can fix this issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

found the solution **removed**

`val sqlCon = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)`

from my code and used zeppelin default **sqlContext**
and it works!!!

Comment: Can you provide the code needed to use the default sqlContext?

Comment: import sys.process._
val jfile = **sqlContext**.jsonFile(s"file:///usr/local/src/knoldus/projects/scaladay_data/scalaDays2015Amsterdam_tweets.json")

jfile.registerTempTable("jTable01")

**sqlContext**.tableNames().foreach(println)

Comment: there is some issue with the line breaks in my above reply please line-break before **val jfile**  and **jfile.registerTempTable**  and **sqlContext.tableNames**

Comment: Thank you, this was for me also the solution.

Answer (score 0):

In my case nothing resolved it until I **removed**

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
```